# How long before you can replay a random event?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I recently failed one of the numerous random events in Grand Theft Auto 5. I eventually came back to the area a few days later and was able to replay it.

How long does it take for a random event to respond? Does switching characters reduce the wait time?

Comment: Switching characters *definitely* reduces the time it takes for a random event to re-occur. If you failed as Michael, you can attempt as Franklin or Trevor almost instantly, whereas Michael would have to wait some time before he can try his luck again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The in-game time that takes the random event to re-appear will vary for each of the encounters:

#### Characters for heists (Paleto, The Big One).

*Example*: [Patrick McReary](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Patrick_McReary#Grand_Theft_Auto_V) and [Taliana Martinez](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Taliana_Martinez#Events_of_GTA_V)

They are *usually* one time only, because the choice will change the available heisters during the course of the game history.

#### Characters for activities (Golf, Tenis).

*Example*: [Castro Lagano](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Castro_Lagano#Events_of_GTA_V)

In case of a failure (the NPC died or got scared) he will re-appear during the next week.

#### Characters that give you stock (BAWSAQ & LCN).

*Example*: [Gray Nicholson](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Gray_Nicholson#Events_of_GTA_V) and [Timm](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Timm#Events_of_GTA_V)

They will reappear, but the time will vary according to the missions played and the distance between the encounter and the player. Most of the time is 72 hours for a failure, 7 days for the rest of the characters and between 1-4 weeks for the same character.

Note that sleeping will not make the random events re-appear faster.